# jquery Как найти ссылку с нужным словом в ее пути

Tags: html, jquery, парсер

К примеру ссылка `/item/vyzyvnaya-panel-videodomofona-tantos-walle-med/` 
Которую я вытащил с сайта. Но у меня их много. Как мне выделить из ряда ссылок только те что имеют слово item в своем пути?

```
$(data).find("a[href^='item']").each(function(){
    res+=$(this).text()+'<br>'+$(this).attr('href');
})
```

такая конструкция ссылки не видит. Если `("a[href^='item']")` поменять на `("a[href^='/item']")`, то понятное дело работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Селектор ^= используется для выбора значений атрибута, начинающихся со строки. Для выбора значений атрибута, содержащих заданную строку, надо использовать селектор *=.

Comment: Благодарю! Надеюсь еще кому то будет полезно!

Comment: Извеняюсь! не работает! В чем может быть проблема? $(data).find("a[href~='item']").each(function(){
 if (res==''){
  res+=$(this).text()+'<br>'+$(this).attr('href');
 }

Comment: Разобрался, нужно было выбрать такой селектор *= в моем случае.Спасибо за направление раскопок!)

Comment: Да, ~= для атрибута, содержащего искомое слово, *= - для строки. Исправлю ответ.